# NetSuite external form

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

I need to present a form to customers to allow interaction with regard to back orders ... Cancel, wait, fill or Add to, etc. What facility does NetSuite offer for things like online forms or Suitelets and if so, do I need a site external to NetSuite?

thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 1):

Customer Center is included in Netsuite. It is possible to inject links to Suitelets into this to provide any missing functionality.

The devil is in the details though in terms of achieving any particular level of functionality and design.

External customer forms are meant as marketing tools.

Comment: Hi and thanks for responding, OK, so this sounds like external/online templates? Docs are awful, what level of functionality do these have? Can you submit a form? Present a list to be chosen from? How far can you take it? Basically, I wanted to show information on a sales order and acknowledge backorder items and give choices of what can be done about them. Do you think this level is possible?  Thanks again

Comment: Custom record is the backend of Online forms. From what I have understood from your comment I recommend you to use the externa suitelets.Suitelets are way flexible and you can even add HTML ,CSS codes to them make it interactive in the UI